# what are the differences between Fork(), Subprocess(),CreateProcess()?

Tags: c

Happy New year to all,
I am writing a client-server programme in which client sends script to the server and server needs to run that script. I have done this in python now I need to do it in C and since I am noob in C, could s.one please tell me how can I replace a subprocess function in C??

Comment: I assume you want to do this on Windows, since `CreateProcess()` is a Windows-only function, but the functions `Fork()` and `Subprocess()` are not part of the Windows API as far as I know. Also, why did you tag the question as `[C++]` if C++ is not mentioned anywhere else in your question? `[c]` and `[c++]` are not equivalent tags. Do you m

Comment: This question cannot be answered in its current form. See in silico's comments.

Comment: [continued from my last comment] Do you mean that you want to write this program in either C or C++? In any case, creating a server that can execute arbitrary scripts provided by clients is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I want to write this in C only

Answer (score 0):

`fork()` - POSIX function that duplicates the current process

`CreateProcess()` - Windows-only function that creates a new process that runs a specified program; the closest thing in Unix is `posix_spawn()`

As for `subprocess`, this appears to be a module exclusive to Python. I can't find a function of that name for Window, Linux, or BSD.

Comment: thank you very much..and sorry for wrong tag..I was not so familiar with tags though..